# When using leaflet maps with cluster options, some circles are not clickable

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have developed a map using leaflet and leaflet.Markercluster. My problem is, that when the circle, at full zoom, is too near the original circle, it is not clickable.

[image: Example of the problem]

In the image, you can see the pop-up that is displayed when you click on a circle. However, when you click on the red circle, no pop-up displays. Firstly, let me emphasise, that the red circle is actually the same as the other circles, I have just coloured red in this image, so I can refer to it. Based on this example, and other examples I have, the problem is when the circle is covered by the original circle (barely visible as an orange shade in the centre).

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of Leaflet.markercluster plugin when you use CircleMarkers and they are spiderfied: see also this post on GIS Stack Exchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259376/reading-attribute-popup-information-from-cluster-presented-points-in-the-map-gen/259538?noredirect=1

This should normally have been fixed by default since 2018 ([PR #846](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/pull/846), included since v1.3.0), which version of Leaflet.markercluster are you using?

If you still have an issue, please raise an issue on the plugin repo, and provide a reproduction sample.

In the meantime, you can also use the old trick of increasing spiderfyDistanceMultiplier option to more than 1, so that the spiderfication is bigger, and the innermost Circle Marker extends beyond the Cluster icon.